# Datatables ColVis search hidden columns

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-5.1

When I use the search box in Datatables it automatically search through the invisible columns.

Is there a possibility to disable this? I only need to filter the visible columns.

[image: Datatables filter]

```
table_advanced = $('#advanced').DataTable({
    "ajax": '{{ route('xxx', ['advanced']) }}',
    columns: [
        {
            name: 'xx',
            data: 'xx',
            visible: false,
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).html("<img src='{{ url('/xxx/') }}/"+oData.xxx+"' style='height:40px'>");
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'xx',
            data: 'xx',
            visible: true,
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).html("<a href='{{ url('/xxx/') }}/"+oData.xxx+"'>"+oData.name+"</a>");
            }
        },
        { name: 'xx', data: 'xx', visible: true },
    ],

    search: false,

    colReorder: true,

    "colVis": {
        "buttonText": "Change columns"
    },

    //"dom": 'BC<"clear">lfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'colvis'
    ],
    dom:
    "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-3 text-center'BC><'col-sm-5'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
});
```

Comment: Please show you datatable configuration Thanks?

Comment: @DipakThoke I added the code above.

Comment: Can't you just set the [searchable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable) parameter in the column definition?